# Help regarding the subject in a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subjects, objects

Could anyone please tell me what would be the subject in the following sentence which I have taken from the *National Geographic* website:

> Providing pools of water for frogs when other water is scarce is just one of the ways elephants engineer ecosystems.

Also, I am confused about what would be the direct object as well as the indirect object in the above sentence.

Comment: _Providing pools of water..._ is the subject. There is no object in a sentence which, in effect, just says _A is B_.

Comment: Isn't "Providing pools of water" is the participle phrase which is considered here an adjective and the subject is the one which has begun with "when"?

Comment: It may be a participle phrase but it isn't an adjective. _One of the ways elephants engineer ecosystems_  **is**  _to provide pools of water for frogs_. _When other water is scarce_  is just an additional phrase describing when this happens.

Comment: Please tell me why there are multiple nouns in "elephants engineer ecosystems"?

Comment: *Engineer* is a verb. I eat bread. You like sunshine. Elephants engineer ecosystems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article *gramma terms*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_g&page=9FJFuU_dyzUI.html),

> subject
>
> Names what or whom a sentence is about. A subject is always a noun (or
>   noun phrase), a pronoun, or a word or word group acting as a noun
>   (such as a **gerund** or a noun clause). For example, the pronoun I is the
>   subject of the sentence I handed in my application for the job. The
>   noun clause Whatever you want to do is the subject of the sentence
>   Whatever you want to do is fine with me.

.

> gerund
>
> Is a verb form ending in -ing that acts as a noun. For example, the
>   gerund *smoking* acts as a noun in the sentence *Smoking can be
>   hazardous to your health.*

So the sentence becomes "(Providing pools of water for frogs when other water is scarce) is just one of the ways (how) elephants engineer ecosystems."

Note that the "engineer" above is a verb.